# Recursive indexing failed at level 3 - Rselenium

Tags: javascript, r, rselenium

I use RSelenium. This following code is a Javascript commnad. I used it in a loop and it works well during the first iteration.  But I have a problem during the second iteration.

Here is the code I have:

```
remDr$executeScript("window.setInterval(function() {window.scrollBy(0, 300);}, 100)", args = list())
```

The error I receive is:

```
Error in out[[wInd]] : recursive indexing failed at level 3
```

Here is the reproducible example as requested:

```
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "chrome", nativeEvents=FALSE)
remDr$open()

url_site <-'https://www.aliexpress.com/category/1909/digital-camera.html?site=glo&pvId=351-350381&attrRel=or&isrefine=y'

remDr$navigate(url_site) # navigates to webpage

remDr$setImplicitWaitTimeout(10000000)
remDr$setTimeout(type = "page load", milliseconds = 10000000)
Sys.sleep(6)
# remDr$executeScript("document.getElementById('alibaba-login-box').getElementById('fm-login-id').value = 'tokenspy@gmail.com';alert();", args = list())

master <- data.frame()
n <- 3 # number of pages to scrape.  80 pages in total.  I just scraped 5 pages for this example.

for(i in 1:n) {

start <- i
if (i == 1 ) {
  i<-''
} 

url_site<-(sprintf('https://www.aliexpress.com/category/1909/digital-camera/%s.html?isrefine=y&site=glo&pvId=351-350381&tag=', i))

cat('display results:',(start),'-',(start+29) ,'in  page', start, 'now \n',url_site,'\n')

site <- url_site
# Sys.sleep(5)
remDr$navigate(site)

remDr$setImplicitWaitTimeout(10000000)
remDr$setTimeout(type = "page load", milliseconds = 10000000)

# Sys.sleep(5)
remDr$executeScript("my_interval = window.setInterval(function() {window.scrollBy(0, 300);}, 100);return;", args = list())
# Sys.sleep(5)
cat('a')

NamewebElems <- remDr$findElements(using = 'css selector', ".detail h3 a")

remDr$executeScript("clearInterval(my_interval);", args = list())
}
```

I noticed that if I remove this line

```
 NamewebElems <- remDr$findElements(using = 'css selector', ".detail h3 a")
```

, the problem is gone and the iteration works properly. But the problem is that I need this line and at the second loop, the error popup and the script stop.

Comment: Try adding a return `remDr$executeScript("window.setInterval(function() {window.scrollBy(0, 300);}, 100); return;", args = list())`

Comment: @jdharrison Unfortunately, that didn't solve it. I still get the error and it stops the script

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example that demonstrates the issue you are having.

Comment: @jdharrison please see the reproducible example I justed added

Comment: Try the dev version `devtools::install_github("ropensci/RSelenium")` an issue with returning multiple web elements has been patched.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that obvisously is not the best but I tested and it works. Use `try ()`  every time you inject a javascript code. The error will still pop up but this method will prevent the iteration to stop. At the same time, the function is triggered successfully. 
So your code should be like this: `try(remDr$executeScript("window.setInterval(function() {window.scrollBy(0, 300);}, 100)", args = list()))`
This working and tested:

```
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "chrome", nativeEvents=FALSE)
remDr$open()

url_site <-'https://www.aliexpress.com/category/1909/digital-camera.html?site=glo&pvId=351-350381&attrRel=or&isrefine=y'

remDr$navigate(url_site) # navigates to webpage

remDr$setImplicitWaitTimeout(10000000)
remDr$setTimeout(type = "page load", milliseconds = 10000000)
Sys.sleep(6)
# remDr$executeScript("document.getElementById('alibaba-login-box').getElementById('fm-login-id').value = 'tokenspy@gmail.com';alert();", args = list())

master <- data.frame()
n <- 3 # number of pages to scrape.  80 pages in total.  I just scraped 5 pages for this example.

for(i in 1:n) {

start <- i
if (i == 1 ) {
  i<-''
} 

url_site<-(sprintf('https://www.aliexpress.com/category/1909/digital-camera/%s.html?isrefine=y&site=glo&pvId=351-350381&tag=', i))

cat('display results:',(start),'-',(start+29) ,'in  page', start, 'now \n',url_site,'\n')

site <- url_site
# Sys.sleep(5)
remDr$navigate(site)

remDr$setImplicitWaitTimeout(10000000)
remDr$setTimeout(type = "page load", milliseconds = 10000000)

# Sys.sleep(5)
try(remDr$executeScript("my_interval = window.setInterval(function() {window.scrollBy(0, 300);}, 100);return;", args = list()))
# Sys.sleep(5)
cat('a')

NamewebElems <- remDr$findElements(using = 'css selector', ".detail h3 a")

try(remDr$executeScript("clearInterval(my_interval);", args = list()))
}
```

You can use `catch` to catch the error in more proper way. Obviously, the best solution is to prevent this error but this answer might help you if your goal is just to make your script working.